# How to find out the ratio of speculators to hedgers?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-exchanges, speculation

When investing, I would like to find out the ratio of speculators and hedgers that are in the market. For some market, such as commodity, I guess you can make an educated guess, yet for many other markets this is not possible. 
Is there any platform that allows you to see such a ratio?

Comment: I can't speak to the futures market but with options, there is no public disclosure for intent.  If I buy calls, I don't have to disclose if I am outright  bullish or for that matter, I am bearish and have hedged short shares. Hence, there is no available data that denotes the ratio of speculators and hedgers.

Answer (score 1):

The CFTC, in its Commitment-of-Traders report, classifies traders as being commercial or non-commercial. A commercial trader is a hedger while a non-commercial trader is a speculator.

https://www.cftc.gov/MarketReports/CommitmentsofTraders/ExplanatoryNotes/index.htm
.

Comment: and is there any way to see the ratio f the two for a particular commodity/stock?